# How do I improve process performance converting a file to array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, activerecord-import

I am using this method to process a single text file that has about 220,000 lines.
It takes a few minutes to process one, but I have lots of them. Are there any recommendations to make this process faster?

```
def parse_list(file_path,import=false)
# Parse the fixed-length fields
   if File.exist?(file_path)
     result=[]
     File.readlines(file_path)[5..-1].each do |rs|
        if rs.length > 140
          r=rs.strip
          unless r=='' 
            filing={
                  'name' => r[0..50].strip,
                  'form' => r[51..70].strip,
                  'type'  => r[71..80].strip,
                  'date' => r[81..90].strip,
                  'location' => r[91..-1].strip
                  }     
              result.push(filing)
          end
        end
     end
     return result
   else
     return false
   end
end
```

---

Update:

Originally, I thought there was massive time savings from using Nex and thetinman's methods so I went on to test them keeping the parsing method consistent.

Using my original `r[].strip` parsing method, but with Nex's `each_line` block method and thetinman's `foreach` methods:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
Nex         8.260000   0.130000   8.390000 (  8.394067)
Thetinman   9.740000   0.120000   9.860000 (  9.862880)
----------------------------------- total: 18.250000sec

                user     system      total        real
Nex        14.270000   0.140000  14.410000 ( 14.397286)
Thetinman  19.030000   0.080000  19.110000 ( 19.118621)
```

Running again using thetinman's `unpack.map` parsing method:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
Nex         9.580000   0.120000   9.700000 (  9.694327)
Thetinman  11.470000   0.090000  11.560000 ( 11.567294)
----------------------------------- total: 21.260000sec

                user     system      total        real
Nex        15.480000   0.120000  15.600000 ( 15.599319)
Thetinman  18.150000   0.070000  18.220000 ( 18.217744)
```

`unpack.map(&:strip)` vs `r[].strip`:  `unpack` with `map` does not seem to increase speed, but is an interesting method to use in the future.

I found a different issue: With the substantial time savings found, I thought, I went on to run Nex and thetinman's methods manually using pry.  This is where I found my computer hanging, just like my original code.  So I went on to test again, but with my original code.

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
Original    7.980000   0.140000   8.120000 (  8.118340)
Nex         9.460000   0.080000   9.540000 (  9.546889)
Thetinman  10.980000   0.070000  11.050000 ( 11.042459)
----------------------------------- total: 28.710000sec

                user     system      total        real
Original   16.280000   0.140000  16.420000 ( 16.414070)
Nex        15.370000   0.080000  15.450000 ( 15.454174)
Thetinman  20.100000   0.090000  20.190000 ( 20.195533)
```

My code, Nex, and thetinman's methods seem comparable, with Nex being the fastest using Benchmark.  However, Benchmark does not seem to tell the whole story because using pry to test the code manually gets all the methods to take substantially longer, so long that I cancel out before getting the result back.

I have some remaining questions:

1. Is there something specific about running something like this in IRB/Pry that would produce these strange results, making the code run massively slower?
2. If I run `original_method.count`, `nex_method.count`, or `thetinmans_method.count`, they all seem to return quickly.
3. Due to memory issues and scalability, it is recommended by thetinman and nex that the original method should not be used. However, in the future are there ways to test memory usage with something like benchmark?

---

Update for NEX, using `activerecord-import`:

@nex, is this what you mean? This seems to run slow for me still, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say:

> import one set of data inside that block.

How do you recommend modifying it?

```
def parse_line(line)
   filing={
   'name' => line[0..50].strip,
   'form' => line[51..70].strip,
   'type'  => line[71..80].strip,
   'date' => line[81..90].strip,
    'location' => line[91..-1].strip
    }    
end

def import_files
 result=[]
 parse_list_nix(file_path){|line|
    filing=parse_line(line)    
    result.push(Filing.new(filing))

 }
 Filing.import result   #result is an array of new records that are all imported at once
end
```

Results from the `activerecord-import` method are, as you can see, substantially slower:

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
import 534.840000   1.860000 536.700000 (553.507644)
------------------------------- total: 536.700000sec

             user     system      total        real
import 263.220000   1.320000 264.540000 (282.751891)
```

Does this slow import process seem normal?

It just seems super slow to me. I'm trying to figure out how to speed this up, but I am out of ideas.

Comment: You haven't given us any sample data to work from, so we haven't got a base to test with. In your tests, remove everything but your file-read method and tweak it until it's as fast as it will go with your data, keeping in mind you do NOT want to pull everything into RAM because that isn't scalable. Then add the split and import and repeat the tests. You can't use pry, or IRB, or a debugger, along with Benchmark and expect any sort of realistic results. They get in the way of how the script runs as a side effect of the conveniences they offer and that translates to slower running code.

Comment: You have't said how many files you're loading, but 5-8 minutes to load a bunch of 220K-line files once a day is nothing to worry about. If it seems slow, you could use some threads to load multiple files at one, or fork processes and have them do it, or have the database load them directly since you're dealing with fixed width fields, which will probably load a whole load faster since it's probably compiled application-specific code.

Comment: @thetinman, It's about 6-9 min per file to import(see benchmark above). I need to import about twenty files. You have some good suggestions. i like your suggestion of importing directly to the database. I will research how it's done.  I have not learned threading, or forking processes, but will look into that too. If you have any good links, please send them my way.  thank you again!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454467/ruby-file-reading-parallelisim/16454804#16454804 for sample code I wrote that shows how to read a file inside a thread. You'll need to modify that code a lot to use it so read through the [Thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html) docs. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data it's hard to confirm this, but, based on the original code, I'd probably write something like this:

```
require 'english'

# Parse the fixed-length fields
def parse_list(file_path,import=false)

  return false unless File.exist?(file_path)

  result=[]
  File.foreach(file_path) do |rs|
    next unless $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER > 5
    next unless rs.length > 140

    r = rs.strip
    if r > '' 
      name, form, type, date, location = r.unpack('A51 A20 A10 A10 A*').map(&:strip)
      result << {
        'name'     => name,
        'form'     => form,
        'type'     => type,
        'date'     => date,
        'location' => location
      }
    end
  end

  result
end
```

220,000 lines isn't a big file where I come from. We get log files 3x that by mid-morning, so using any file I/O that slurps the file is out. Ruby's IO class has two methods for line-by-line I/O and a number that return arrays. You want the former because they are scalable. Unless you can guarantee that the file being read will fit comfortably in Ruby's memory avoid the later.

Comment: why have .foreach(file_path)[5..-1] and next unless $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER > 5?

Comment: That's a vestige from the original code. Taking it out. Thanks.

Comment: does the slow import process seem normal to you? or would you make further recommendations to improve?

Comment: Take a look at the benchmark in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16446731/128421 which loaded 5,540,058 lines in about 35 seconds. Changing from the use of `gsub` to `unpack` wouldn't change the times that much. If you are loading big files, and can't guarantee they'll fit into RAM, you have to load line-by-line, so `foreach` and `each_line` are your best choices.

Comment: I took your and Nex's recommendation on your first posts, see the above edits. After I removed `readlines` I believe fixed the memory issue. I then added an import process using `activerecord-import` and benchmarked it and I felt it was slow.  Didn't know if there was more I could do to optimize it.  I don't know what type of performance to expect with a 8GB, Core i7 MacAir. Maybe there is no more I can do.

Comment: You're using a laptop that was designed for portability and has lots of speed tradeoffs as a result. In other words, it isn't designed for production work. Put the code on something with a wired-ethernet connection, and a big CPU and high-speed drives, and you'll probably see a lot faster throughput. Put it on a machine on the same switch as the database and that'd help too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're filling up your memory. What are you going to do with that result? Does it have to linger in your memory as a whole or would it be an option to just process it line by line with a block?

Also you should not use readlines here. Do something like this instead since it uses an Enumerator:

```
def parse_list(file_path, import=false)
  i = 0
  File.open(file_path,'r').each_line do |line|
    line.strip!
    next if (i+=1) < 5 || line.length < 141
    filing = { 'name' => r[0..50].strip,
               'form' => r[51..70].strip,
               'type'  => r[71..80].strip,
               'date' => r[81..90].strip,
               'location' => r[91..-1].strip }
    yield(filling) if block_given?
  end
end

# and calling it like this:
parse_list('/tmp/foobar'){ |filling|
  Filing.new(filing).import
}
```

Comment: I plan on using activerecord-import (https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to import the records into a my Postgres database.

Comment: So you could use the block-version I provided and import one set of data inside that block. This way you don't have to keep the whole array in memory and the algorithm will run much faster. This is of course not noticeable with a few hundred records, but with over 200k records it's definitely worth it imho.

Comment: I edited my initial code. Hope this clears things up. If not, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something, or you are. Why would you run Filing.new(filing).import on every erration(sp?)? "Filing.import result" for example is suppose to take the entire array of new records and import them all at once based on the best method per the specific database.  Should I not be using activerecord-import gem? see https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki